# Show that $\sqrt{\sum_{i}^n X_i} - \sqrt{n} \to Y \sim \mathcal{N}(\mu, \sigma^2)$ in distribution.

Tags: probability-theory, central-limit-theorem, probability-limit-theorems

> Let $(X_n)_n$ be a sequence of i.i.d. random variables with
>   $\mathbb{E}X_1 = 1, \operatorname{Var}(X_1) = 3$.
>
> Show that $\sqrt{\sum_{i}^n X_i} - \sqrt{n} \to Y \sim
>  \mathcal{N}(\mu, \sigma^2)$ in distribution for some numbers $\mu,
>  \sigma \in \mathbb{R}$ and determine those numbers.

**My attempt**:

$$\mathbb{P}\{\sqrt{\sum_{i=1}^n X_i} -  \sqrt{n} \leq x\} = \mathbb{P}\{0 \leq \sum X_i \leq (x + \sqrt{n})^2\} $$

$$= \mathbb{P}\{\sum X_i \leq (x+ \sqrt{n})^2\} - \mathbb{P}\{\sum X_i < 0\}$$

and this last probability seems $0$ to me. Because $\sum X_i < 0$ is not possible, or the square root would not be well defined. But I think this is suspicious because it isn't given that $\sum X_i \geq 0$. What do you think?

I want to apply the central limit theorem, but my problem is that the right hand side depends on $n$, so this isn't allowed.

Maybe I have to use some continuity argument to proceed?

Comment: *Hint.* If $S_n=\sum_{i=1}^{n}X_i$, then you may write $$ \sqrt{S_n}-\sqrt{n}=\frac{S_n-n}{\sqrt{n}}\cdot\frac{1}{\sqrt{\frac{S_n}{n}}+1}. $$ As for the sign issue, you are right. To avoid the sign issue, I guess that you can safely assume that $X_i$ are non-negative without harming the essence of the problem.

Comment: You might take the absolute value of the sum. You can use the so-called [delta method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delta_method) or the answer at https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/241504/central-limit-theorem-for-square-roots-of-sums-of-i-i-d-random-variables to get $\mathcal{N}\left(0, \frac{3^2}{4\times 1^2} \right)$ i.e. $\mathcal{N}\left(0, \frac{9}{4} \right)$ as the limiting distribution

Comment: @SangchulLee Thanks for the hint. Unfortunately, I don't see how I can use it. I see the first factor looks a lot like what I want for applying CLT.

Comment: Converging together lemma (a.k.a. Slutsky's theorem) tells that if $X_n \to X$ in distribution and $Y_n \to c$ in distribution where $c$ is constant, then $X_n + Y_n \to X+c$ and $X_n Y_n \to cX$ in distribution. So you may investigate $(S_n-n)/\sqrt{n}$ and $1/(\sqrt{S_n/n}+1)$ separately. The former one is in the purview of CLT, and the latter one converges to some constant by the law of large numbers.

Comment: I didn't know about that lemma. Thanks. I will try to prove it first.

Comment: Correcting my earlier comment, the limiting distribution should have been $\mathcal{N}\left(0, \frac{3}{4\times 1^2} \right)$

Comment: Using my seemingly unrelated question: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2798924/f-n-to-f-x-n-to-x-implies-f-nx-n-to-fx?noredirect=1#comment5770710_2798924 , and using the fact that $F_{Z_n} \to F_Z$ uniformly if $Z_n \to Z$ in distribution if $F_Z$ is continuous, I managed to go further with the attempt I made. And I found the same answer as you told me. Thanks both for the useful comments.